# Is there any advanced optimization methods in keras, if not then how can i use them?

Tags: keras

I know what the optimizers are in keras BUT I am talking about methods like stochastic average gradient (SAG) or Stochastic Variance-Reduced Gradient (SVRG)?
did anyone use it before in his projects? How?

Comment: Here is the list of optimizers available in Keras [https://keras.io/optimizers/](https://keras.io/optimizers/)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried RMSprop over SGD recently on a project. For my application, RMSprop trains the network much faster than SGD. Switching optimizers in Keras is really simple, for example switching from SGD to RMSprop

```
rmsprop = RMSprop(lr=0.0001)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=rmsprop,
              #optimizer = sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

As pointed by Sergii in the comment, there is a list of optimizers from which you can choose.